# SQL update doesn't update with the given value

Tags: sql-server

I'm having a problem so weird. When I execute (via PHP or directly via SQL) this sentence:

```
UPDATE event SET adGroupId = 23903638857 WHERE id = 1
```

It doesn't work, and the `eventId = 1` is updated with `adGroupId = 2147483647`

Always the same, row by row. Could it be a SQL caché problem, or something similar?

I don't really understand this issue...

Comment: what is the data type of the adGroupId column?

Comment: `event` is reserved keyword use `UPDATE [event] SET adGroupId = 23903638857 WHERE id = 1`

Comment: @tinka Maybe even prefix it with the schema name? (if there is one..)

Comment: Can you create a reproducible example?

Comment: event is NOT a reserved keyword (or it was not in SQL Server 2012): https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189822(v=sql.110).aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the data type of the adGroupId column is `INT` then change it to `BIGINT` or to `DECIMAL` with a large enough digit count.

2,147,483,647 is the maximum value what an `INT` column can store and 23,903,638,857 is bigger than that, so SQL Server truncates it (and you got a warning somewhere for sure).

`BIGINT` can store integer values from -9,223,372,036,854,775,808 to 9,223,372,036,854,775,807.

For further reference: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187745.aspx